Permeability and base material considerations for paver project in freeze/thaw climate
I'm DIYing my first backyard project and would love to get some feedback about the paver patio I'm planning to build. We're building this in Denver, where there's a fair amount freeze/thaw action in the winter and spring. We've picked out the pavers and had them delivered—they're porcelain and will have minimal gaps between the pavers, filled with polymeric sand. So, this top layer is not exactly "permeable", although surely some small amount of water will seep through. My unknown is mostly about what type of road base and geotextile fabric would be best considering the climate and the paver material. Should I be trying to keep water out at all costs, going with a recycled concrete roadbase that will set up really tightly, or something that itself is more permeable?

How permeable is the subgrade soil?

Not very, it's mostly clay

Do you have any slope to the area, like could you daylight a drainage layer?

Unfortunately, I don't think I could daylight a drainage layer, the outer edge of the patio will be up against sod that sits flush to the top edge of the patio. I'm cutting in a slope at a 1:72 grade (1/6" drop for every 12" distance away from the house).

Trying to keep water out completely is a fool's errand. You won't accomplish that. You must allow for drainage at a reasonable flow rate so you don't have pooled water freezing and tearing up your work.
Of course, it does help to have a fairly sealed surface and adequate slope, but that's something you'll decide based on the situation.

Is there a roadbase you'd recommend in order to achieve drainage at a reasonable flow rate? Same question about the geotextile fabric...

No. My knowledge of such things is fairly general. You might have a chat with someone local to see what's available and what is preferred by professionals.
